# Radio button not working in wordpress 7

Tags: javascript, wordpress

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('input.check1').click(function(){
$('#show1').show();$('#show2').hide();
});
$('input.check2').click(function(){
$('#show2').show();$('#show1').hide();
});
});
</script>
```

This is the Javascript code that I'm trying to use in one of my Wordpress 7.1 pages to show and hide a 'div' part that contains a table, using radio buttons. Below is code for the radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="chec" class="check1" checked="checked">Option 1
<input type="radio" name="chec" class="check2">Option 2
```

But it is not working. I don't know what to do, maybe the Javascript is not triggering?

Comment: replace `$(function(){` with `jQuery(function($) {`

Comment: Latest version is 3.7.1

Comment: ya it is wordpress 3.7.1...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    $('.check1').click(function(){
    $('#show1').show();
    $('#show2').hide();
});
   $('.check2').click(function(){
   $('#show2').show();
   $('#show1').hide();
});
});
</script>
```

Also make sure you have the script source in your header.

Comment: I hv placed the javascript in header.php under <head> tag. but it is still not working.... using wordpress 3.7.1...

Answer (score 0):

replace all '$' sign by 'jQuery'

As wordpress by default uses jQuery=noconflict